# How to generate a valid Private Key using CLI?

Tags: solidity, private-key, cryptography

I am trying to create a private key which is valid and can be used for production work.

What tool should I use to create a Valid Private key on my system using Terminal/CLI?

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `cast` to quickly interact with networks on the Terminal. I think you can refer to the cast [docs](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-wallet-new) on how to create a new private key pair.

For your specific case, I think `cast wallet new` will do the job. Please refer to the example output I've tested on my Terminal.

```
$ cast wallet new
Successfully created new keypair.
Address:     <wallet_address>
Private key: <corresponding_private_key>
```

---

Edit: Thought more about the question, and it seems like there are more interpretations to Private Key than just the one for a EOA. If you were intending to ask something about creating Public/Private Key Pairs to sign/verify things, there is also a Linux [built-in](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) command

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

which will do the job.

Comment: thanks ser. This worked for my tutorial.